# Prevent a navigation bar menu to wrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When creating a navbar with Bootstrap ([jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/tuhocusoti/1/)) and redimensionning to a small *browser width*, the menu wraps like this :

[image]

**How can we make that the menu doesn't wrap, and stay in a single line?** (the buttons /search field should go on top of the brand, the brand might be masked)

---

Here's the code of the navbar:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="navbar-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </span>
              </div>
            </div></li>
          <li><a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="http://gget.it/ornlbhjq/edit.php" id="newpost">New post</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdown">Login / Signup&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the list items in `.navigation` have a `display:block;` Wich automaticly consumes all the space they can take.

So change

```
.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

To

```
.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried in the jsbin (http://jsbin.com/tuhocusoti/1/) @SKeurentjes but it doesn't work.